# Refund order and invoice api not working

Tags: magento2, magento2-api

I am trying to create credit memo and refund order and invoice via following api call:-
'/V1/invoice/36/refund'

and my array is as below, which i am converting later to JSON

```
$postData = [
                            "items" => $invoice_item,
                            "notify" => true,
                             "isOnline"=> 0,
                                "arguments" => [
                                "shipping_amount" => $order->shipping_amount,
                                "adjustment_positive" => 0,
                                "adjustment_negative" => 0,
                                "extension_attributes" => [
                                    "return_to_stock_items" => $order_item_arr
                                    ]
                                ],
                            "appendComment" => true,
                            "comment" => [
                                "extension_attributes" => [],
                                "comment" => "string",
                                "is_visible_on_front" => 0
                            ],
                        ];
```

I am getting the following error "Creditmemo Document Validation Error(s):
We can't create creditmemo for the invoice.
The creditmemo contains product item that is not part of the original order.
The "MT07-S-Gray" product is not part of the current creditmemo."

Though I have checked well the existence of product.

Comment: Did you find what the issue was? I am getting same

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will be the answer for you but I'been hitting my head on the wall for a while just find out that I wasn't passing the correct order if in the post url E.G: `/rest/V1/order/{{OrderId}}/refund` the body was correct but the OrderId was not the correct id after updating all test working I have only one issue order status not updating it `closed`.

UPDATED: By the way if you have multiple items then it gets trick. the field `"order_item_id":` value must be the configurable `item_id` for the child item and `"return_to_stock_items":[]` value(s) must have the child `item_id` otherwise you will get the same error:

May help someone!

Comment: can we Refund Orders to Payment Method ?